# Fitting a spline to data with FindFit?

Tags: fitting, interpolation, splines

I am trying to find a function that fits my almost linear data. A high order polynomial model has too much residual. So I was hoping to use Mathematica to **fit splines** to the **curve**.

This is what I would like to see in an example.

- `FindFit` with a spline function
- How to get model stats like what `LinearModelFit` provides.
- How to dump the spline terms and control points so I can implement in "C"

I can then use the cubic spline on my embedded platform.

So can I get a symbolic representation of this function so I can implement it?

You can get the [sample data here](https://gist.github.com/3702965)

Comment: Do you need a fit or an interpolation? You're using both terms, but they aren't the same.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE by the way. Of Dutch descend, by any chance?

Comment: Yep, My great grand father was from Holland.

Comment: I really need a fit.

Comment: can we have a sample of your data? is it only y-values or {x,y} pairs? Full data would be much better. And do you need the fit curve to pass exactly through all points or just reflect on general trend?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3702965

Comment: The function just needs to reflect a trend. I added a link to the data. It is just {x,y} pairs.

Comment: Are you sure they are {x,y} and not {y,x}? I mean: the integers are `y` values?

Comment: You might like to have a look at `BSplineCurve`: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineCurve.html#30165982

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks for the link. It was exactly what i wanted. I never thought of looking there because I thought of BSplineCurve as only a graphics function.

Comment: @witkamp yes, it's strange that these examples are on the `BSplineCurve` documentation page rather than the one for `BSplineBasis`. To get the goodness-of-fit statistics you can probably use `BSplineBasis` with `LinearModelFit` rather than constructing the design matrix manually as shown in the example. I'd have posted an answer except I wasn't sure if that was what you were looking for and haven't used splines for anything before, so I have no real familiarity with them. Please feel free to self-answer if you like.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Implementation of smoothing splines function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33262/280)," "[How to make BSplineFunction pass each data point and naturally smooth?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26893/280)"

Comment: It amazes me this is such a highly voted question with a highly voted answer that *does not answer the question* an arbitrary polynomial is not a spline.

Comment: @george2079, I agree! I just need the correct answer to accept!

Answer (score 6):

Taking your data in account from link you provided:

```
data={{......}};
```

Find the model:

```
model = Fit[data, x^# & /@ Range[0, 10], x]

20.2513 + 43.3389 x - 0.208411 x^2 + 0.193888 x^3 - 0.0341689 x^4 + 
 0.00281455 x^5 - 0.000131003 x^6 + 3.64629*10^-6 x^7 - 
 6.01724*10^-8 x^8 + 5.43205*10^-10 x^9 - 2.06702*10^-12 x^10
```

Verify it is more or less correct:

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.02], Opacity[.02], Red]], 
 Plot[model, {x, -7, 55}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.005]], 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

The blue line inside is your model. Red line is your data points blended together (too many of them) with applied opacity. I've chosen so many polynomial terms to take in account well little bent at the beginning. You can play with number of polynomial terms.

Export your model to C:

```
CForm[model]

20.251253486790134 + 43.33892854755122*x - 0.20841104603541305*Power(x,2) + 
   0.19388822209706186*Power(x,3) - 0.03416888859439315*Power(x,4) + 
   0.0028145533596680857*Power(x,5) - 0.0001310033312242676*Power(x,6) + 
   3.646291289683582e-6*Power(x,7) - 6.017238075935027e-8*Power(x,8) + 
   5.432049184033492e-10*Power(x,9) - 2.0670190082996488e-12*Power(x,10)
```

Comment: Just in case this works much better for the left "tail" `f[x_]:=24.9*x + 2.206*x*Sin@x + x^2*Sin@x + Tan[0.2407*x] - 5.611*x^2`

Comment: If you're expecting to be doing high-order polynomial fits, I would recommend using `LinearModelFit[]`, taking one basis function at a time, and monitoring the value of `"AdjustedRSquared"` to guard against overfitting (or use the fancier methods, such as cross-validation).

Comment: @belisarius Ahh, what's the name of the program you used to get this expression? The one that fits models of different complexity to the data...

Comment: @Ajasja, [Eureqa](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa)?

Comment: @J.M. The name is `Formulize` now. And they now sell cloud time for parallel evaluations.

Comment: @belisarius I just downloaded it. Very cool program. User friendly too. I wonder how it compares to the commercial  Mathematica 'equivalent' at http://www.evolved-analytics.com/

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for pointing me to that program. Very interesting. Reminds me of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6117644/615464) answer of mine.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries My experiments with `Formulize` gave me both good and bad results. If you do know a few things about the model, you can inject that knowledge into the software in several (sometimes subtle) ways. It is sometimes very slow to converge to a good solution, but I never bought real computing power (a cloud grid) to be serious about this complain.

Comment: @belisarius That's the one I had in mind. Thanks.

Comment: The residuals for the 12th order polynomial are too high. That is why I would like to fit a SPLINE to the curve. Also this needs to be implemented on an embedded platform with software FP.

Comment: @witkamp, with what you've just said, I'm not even entirely sure that a smoothing spline is the best way to go about it. As a start, could you edit your question to talk a bit about the provenance of your data?

Comment: @witkamp once you found a spline fit, like [**this**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0c0rpcn4bku6m-gl8v85) or like [**this**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0c0rpcn4bku6m-dws29b) how do you intend to port it to C ? It is still in Mathematica intrinsic form. Won't you have exactly same problem as you had with InterpolatingFunction?

Comment: @J.M. I added a comment above about a spline.

Comment: @J.M The data table maps mV to Deg F. for a k-Type Thermocouple.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I would implement the BSplineBasis function in C use it to calculate the spline.

Comment: @J.M. What other methods would you recommend?

Comment: As I said @witkamp, please edit that information into your question...