# How to interpolate 3D data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Here comes some sample data

```
data = {{8.546, 10.3, -3270}, {8.525, 10.2, -3211}, {8.554, 10.1, -3162},
        {8.609, 10, -3120}, {8.709, 9.9, -3085}, {8.966, 9.89, -3084}, 
        {9.204, 9.9, -3083}, {9.421, 10, -3108}, {9.588, 10.1, -3133},
        {9.740, 10.2, -3157}, {9.885, 10.3, -3180}};

L1 = ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Green], PointSize[0.02]}}]
```

which gives

[image]

My question: Is there a way to interpolate these data and obtain much more points between them? I want that many points so as to obtain a smooth solid line in 3D space. Moreover, is it possible to join these data, like the option `Joined -> True` in `ListPlot`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your data always ordered?

Comment: @J.M. Most of the times, yes.

Comment: I asked because the unordered case is much harder. In this case, you could just do `Show[L1, Graphics3D[{Green, Line[data]}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. The line is OK< but what about the interpolation? I need plenty of more data between the points, so as to be able to draw a smooth line.

Comment: You can modify @J.M.'s method to draw a smooth curve: i.e. ``Graphics3D[{Green, BSplineCurve[data]}]``. It will not go directly through all points, but will produce a nice picture.

Comment: @Shadow, you could use a method like the one in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898) to make an interpolating `BSplineCurve[]`, if that is what is wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Interpolation` still works in 3D:

```
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}],   InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02]}}],
 ParametricPlot3D[f[u], {u, 1, Length[data]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
]
```

[image]

**Sampling**

You can choose how you want your sampled points to be spaced. For example you might just want points evenly spaced between your existing points:

```
tsData1 = With[{u = Rescale@Range[Length[data]]},
  Transpose[{u, data}]
];

f1 = Interpolation[tsData1, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

data1 = Table[f1[u], {u, 0, 1, 0.025}];

ListPointPlot3D[{data1, data}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02]}, {Blue, PointSize[0.02]}}]
```

[image]

Or you might want point evenly distributed along the length of the line:

```
tsData2 = With[{u = 
    Rescale@Prepend[Accumulate[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]], 0]
  },
  Transpose[{u, data}]
];

f2 = Interpolation[tsData2, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

data2 = Table[f2[u], {u, 0, 1, 0.025}];

ListPointPlot3D[{data2, data}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02]}, {Blue, PointSize[0.02]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can we create a new list `data2` containing let's say 1000 interpolated points between the existing ones?

Comment: Yeah, just `data2 = Table[f[u], {u, 1, Length[data], (Length[data] - 1)/(1000 - 1)}]`

Answer (score 1):

So this is the best I could do, maybe improvements can be made, but I don't know. If you want to plot a line, you need to use ParametricPlot3D, which needs inputs along the lines of {x,y(x),z(x)}. So we're going to split your data into two pieces and use interpolation on them. The first datapoint is irritating to the interpolation though, so I left it out.

```
dataY = Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}, {i, 2, Length[data]}];
intY = Interpolation[dataY];
dataZ = Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 3]]}, {i, 2, Length[data]}];
intZ = Interpolation[dataZ];
Show[{ListPointPlot3D[data,
PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Green], PointSize[0.02]}}, PlotRange -> All],
   ParametricPlot3D[{x, intY[x], intZ[x]}, {x, 8.53, 9.89}]}]
```

This is the result:

[image]

There are probably some improvements that can be made on this, but I think this is the general idea that you should follow.