# Smooth region plot from list of points

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, regions, mesh

I have function that is costly to evaluate, `fun[x,y]`, that takes two real arguments and returns True or False. I am trying to visualize in the x,y-plane the region where the function returns True.

I took a sample of points on a 2-dimensional grid on the x,y-plane, so I generated a list of the form:

`{{x1,y1,True}, {x2,y2,True}, {x3,y3,False}, ...}`

consisting of the coordinates of each point and the return value of the function.

Using `ArrayPlot` I can turn this into a visualization of the region where the function is true, but it is ugly because it has very straight edges. Is there a way to obtain a smoothed boundary?

Here is an example

```
fun[x_, y_] := (Boole[x^2 <= y])
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, fun[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], {1, 2}];
ListPlot[{Cases[data, {_, _, 1}], Cases[data, {_, _, 0}]}[[All, 
  All, {1, 2}]]]
```

[image]

Of course, `fun[x,y]` is a dummy example, in reality it is expensive to evaluate. It would be nice if could get a smooth region boundary.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I added an example.

Comment: *Sigh* As code?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Done

Comment: Hm. Can we assume that the value of fun depends on the fulfillment of few rather smooth inequalities?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Well, let's assume it is reasonably smooth, otherwise there is not plotting possible!

Answer (score 5):

Then what about this: I interpolate with a `BezierFunction` and plot it's superlevel set:

```
dx = 0.1;
fun[x_, y_] := (Boole[x^2 <= y])
data = Table[{x, y, fun[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1, dx}, {y, 0, 1, dx}];
f = BezierFunction[data];
Show[
 Quiet@RegionPlot[f[x, y][[3]] >= .5, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
 ListPlot[{
    Cases[Flatten[data, 1], {_, _, 1}],
    Cases[Flatten[data, 1], {_, _, 0}]}[[All, All, {1, 2}]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

`BezierFunction` only accepts arguments in the unit interval/square/cube. At least for rectangular domains, we can rescale and shift coordinates to obtain a slightly more flexible tool:

```
maxx = 3;
maxy = 2;
minx = miny = -1;
dx = 0.1;
dy = 0.2;
fun[x_, y_] := (Boole[x^2 <= y])
data = Table[{x, y, fun[x, y]}, {x, minx, maxx, dx}, {y, miny, maxy, dy}];
f = BezierFunction[data.DiagonalMatrix[{1./(maxx - minx), 1./(maxy - minx), 1.}]];
Show[
 Quiet@RegionPlot[ f[(x - minx)/(maxx - minx) , (y - miny)/(maxy - miny) ][[3]] >= .5, {x, minx, maxx}, {y, miny, maxy}], 
 ListPlot[{Cases[Flatten[data, 1], {_, _, 1}], Cases[Flatten[data, 1], {_, _, 0}]}[[All, All, {1, 2}]]]
]
```

[image]

However, I do not know how to get rid of the requirement of even spacings of data points... Maybe one can also experiment with `Interpolation` to obtain suitable functions `f`. My experience with `Interpolation` was that the solutions were a bit too tight to data. Using [smoothing splines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33206/implementation-of-smoothing-splines-function) instead may also help.

Comment: That looks nice. I'll try it on my data and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: How do the $u,v$ parameters on the Bezier relate to my original $x,y$? In this example the $x,y$ go from 0 to 1, but in general this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yes, the even spacing is too tight a requirement.

Comment: Okay, I posted a new approach...

Comment: Yes! I was looking at it. Massive! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

And yet another approach. First, I try to detect the region of the interface between `0`- and `1`-valued points. Afterwards I use the minimimizer of the Dirichlet energy with respect `0`- and `1`-valued boundary conditions in this region; the final interface will be the `1/2`-levelset.

First, the data points:

```
maxx = 3;
maxy = 2;
minx = miny = -1;
fun[x_, y_] := (Boole[x^2 <= y]);
nn = 600;
data0 = Transpose[{RandomReal[{minx, maxx}, nn], RandomReal[{miny, maxy}, nn]}];
data1 = Join[data0, Transpose[{fun @@@ data0}], 2];
listplot = Show[Graphics[], ListPlot[{Cases[data1, {_, _, 1}], Cases[data1, {_, _, 0}]}[[All, All, {1, 2}]], 
   PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97][3], ColorData[97][4]}]
  ]
```

[image]

Next, we coarsly detect the interface region:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["TriangleLink`"];
R = TriangleCreate[];
pts = data1[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
TriangleSetPoints[R, pts];
S = TriangleTriangulate[R, "a1.0"];
pts = TriangleGetPoints[S];
faces = TriangleGetElements[S];
pos = Flatten[Position[Equal @@@ Partition[data1[[Flatten[faces], 3]], 3], False, 1]];
nfaces = faces[[pos]];
plist = Union @@ nfaces;
npts = pts[[plist]];
lookuptable = AssociationThread[plist -> Range[Length[plist]]];
nfaces = Partition[Lookup[lookuptable, Flatten[nfaces]], 3];
nullpos = Flatten[Position[data1[[plist, 3]], 0, 1]];
onepos = Flatten[Position[data1[[plist, 3]], 1, 1]];
R = MeshRegion[npts, Polygon[nfaces]];
With[{edges = Developer`ToPackedArray[MeshCells[R, 1][[All, 1]]]},
  R0 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R], Line[Select[edges, SubsetQ[nullpos, #] &]]];
  R1 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R], Line[Select[edges, SubsetQ[onepos, #] &]]];
  ];
GraphicsRow[{Show[listplot, R], Show[listplot, R0, R1]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Finally, we solve a boundary value problem. This can be done easier with the `NDSolve` facilities, but as I am not that much into these details, I do it a bit more verbatim.

```
S = DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001];
n = Length[MeshCoordinates[S]];
nullpos = Flatten[Position[RegionMember[R0]@MeshCoordinates[S], True, 1]];
onepos = Flatten[Position[RegionMember[R1]@MeshCoordinates[S], True, 1]];
plist = Join[onepos, nullpos];
Module[{vd, sd, cdata, mdata, dpde, dbc, load, damping, bcdata, y, x, u},
  Rdiscr = ToElementMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> MeshCoordinates[S],
    "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[MeshCells[S, 2][[All, 1]]]},
    "MeshOrder" -> 1,
    "NodeReordering" -> False];
  vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables","Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}]; 
  sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {Rdiscr}]; 
  cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,
    "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}}, 
    "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}, "LoadCoefficients" -> {{0}}
    ];
  mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
  dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
  dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd]; {load, 
    stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["All"];
  ];
costraints = SparseArray[Transpose[{Range[Length[plist]], plist}] -> 1., {Length[plist], n}, 0.];
L = ArrayFlatten[{{stiffness, Transpose[costraints]}, {costraints, 0.}}];
b = Join[ConstantArray[0., n], ConstantArray[1., Length[onepos]], ConstantArray[0., Length[nullpos]]];
x = LinearSolve[L, b][[1 ;; n]];
f = ElementMeshInterpolation[{Rdiscr}, x];
GraphicsGrid[{
  {HighlightMesh[S, {0, nullpos}], HighlightMesh[S, {0, onepos}]},
  {Plot3D[f[u, v], Element[{u, v}, S]],
   Show[ContourPlot[f[u, v] == 1/2, Element[{u, v}, S]], listplot]
   }}
 , ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

This should also work for quite general domains.

Comment: For me the last box does not work and gives an error about things not having the same shape. "12.0.0 for Linux" (Also on 11.3.0 for Linux)

Comment: @Bvothe Hm. Apparently, _Mathematica_ does not like if I evaluate ``      Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];`` in the `Module`. Putting it outside seems to work, though. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use the function as `RegionFunction` in `ContourPlot`. In the example below, I desined `expensivefunction` such that it keeps track about the evaluation points. You may use the options `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` to control the amount of function evaluations and the accuracy of the sampling of the domain.

```
expensivefunction[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (
   Internal`StuffBag[pts, {x, y}];
   x^2 + 0.1 Sin[3 Pi x] + y^2 <= 1.
   );
f = {x, y} \[Function] expensivefunction[x, y];

pts = Internal`Bag[{}];
g = ContourPlot[1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2},
   RegionFunction -> f,
   Mesh -> All,
   BoundaryStyle -> Black,
   PlotPoints -> 2,
   MaxRecursion -> 2
   ];
Show[{g, Graphics[Point[Internal`BagPart[pts, All]]]}]
```

[image]

With higher values for `MaxRecursion` you get better resolution, but of course, also mor points to evaluate your function on. The following is the same as above but with `MaxRecursion -> 5`:

[image]

For your example, one could try this

```
expensivefunction[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (Internal`StuffBag[pts, {x, y}];x^2 - y <= 0.);
f = {x, y} \[Function] expensivefunction[x, y];
pts = Internal`Bag[{}];
g = ContourPlot[1., {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> All,
   PlotPoints -> {10, 5},
   MaxRecursion -> 0,
   RegionFunction -> f
   ];
Show[{g, Graphics[Point[Internal`BagPart[pts, All]]]}]
Internal`BagLength[pts]
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be impossible to tell `ContourPlot` exactly from which points to sample...

[image]

Comment: This is a nice approach. But I would like to control the sampled points manually, if possible. So I generate the points myself, then the question is how I can plot a nice region out of it.