# Derivative of an interpolation function is noisy

Tags: numerics, interpolation

I have a set of numerical data of 1501 points, in the form of $\{x_i,a_i\}$ which I uploaded to [here](https://textuploader.com/dnslr) and [here](https://pastebin.com/Ccvm7Bgp).

I need to compute the numerical derivative of this data. In particular, I need the quantities

\begin{equation}
C=\frac{1}{\left| \frac{da}{dx} \right|}, \hspace{1cm} D = C' = \frac{dC}{dx}
\end{equation}

To do this, I interpolated the data given in the link,

```
data = Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/Ccvm7Bgp"];
Interp = Interpolation[data];
Plot[Interp[x], {x, 0, x[[1501]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Then I computed `C` by

```
DInterp[x_] := Interp'[x];
C[x_] := 1/Abs[DInterp[x]];
```

But `DInterp` and, consequently, `C` (shown below) are very noisy, let alone sC'$:

This is the derivative of the interpolation, `Dinterp`

[image: This is the derivative of the interpolation, Dinterp]

This is `C`

[image: This is C]

How can I solve this? I need to determine $C$ and $C'$ very precisely, how to I get rid of the noise to achieve this?

Comment: Not at a computer right now, but one look at your axes tells me you chose a poor scaling of your variables.

Comment: The numbers you are working with are so small that your computations can not be made accurately enough using machine arithmetic. You can try  rescaling as J.M. suggests or maybe try working with arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90130/1871

Comment: Just tested your data, only to encounter `Interpolation::inddp` warning. Also, something is apparently wrong with `{x, 0, x[[1501]]}`. Please double-check your code sample.

Comment: J.M. and m_goldberg, thank you for the replies. Would it make any difference working with different accuracies? xzczd, I meant to write {x, 0, data[[1501,1]]}, not use x in both places, sorry about that.

Comment: I think the problem is "quantisation noise" in your data.  Your step size is small compared with the accuracy with which the numbers are specified. I think you can get better results by e.g. taking only every 10th point.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Derivative of an interpolating function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176165/34893).

Comment: mikado and  AccidentalFourierTransform, thank you!

Comment: Please correct those mistakes by clicking the **edit** button in the left bottom corner of your post.